# Loop to check multiple polygons overlap in r

Tags: qgis, r, overlay, overlapping-features, loop

I have a set of polygons (available here: http://ulozto.cz/x39ELbFt/polygons-zip) created in QGis and processed in R. I would like to know **if they are overlapping or not, and if yes, where is the overlapped area (and between which polygons)?** I know that to figure this out I can use tools:

- over{sp} - return data.frame not a spatial object!
- intersect{raster}
- gIntersection{rgeos}

I can find intersection by comparing 1 by 1 polygon each time step. However as my real data are huge, I prefer to make a loop and include the iteration of polygons:

- intersect(p1, p2)
- intersect(p1, p3)
- intersect(p1, p4)
- intersect(p2, p3)
- etc...

For the moment, I made up only loop for one polygon intersecting another 3. From resulting list of overlapping polygons I can't however really say which polygons are overlapped. And if they are not (p1 and p4) this NULL value is not included in my resulting list!

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(spatstat)
library(rgdal)     

setwd("D:/...")
p1<- readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer="p1")
p2<- readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer="p2")
p3<- readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer="p3")
p4<- readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer="p4")

ab<-list(p2, p3, p4)

# my loop only for 1 polygon, not for combinations of polygons
by two intersection methods

# intersection by gIntersection{rgeos}
int1<-list()
for (i in 1:length(ab)){
int11<-gIntersection(p1, ab[[i]], byid = FALSE)
int1[[i]]<-int11
}

# intersection by intersect{raster}
rst.int<-list()
for (i in 1:length(ab)){
rst.int1<-intersect(p1, ab[[i]])
rst.int[[i]]<-rst.int1
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played with `assign()`, `ls()`, and `mget()` to accomplish something that I believe will improve your workflow. First I use `ls()` to get a list of all environment variables that start with "p":

```
names_poly <- ls(pattern='^p.')
```

I used `combn()` to find all the unique combinations of polygons

```
combos <- combn(names_poly,2)
```

I looped over `combos` using `get()` to fetch the polygons `i` and `j` named in `combos`. I also used `assign()` to create a new object whose name is pasted together (e.g. `int_p1_p2`)

```
for(k in seq_along(combos[1,])){
    i <- combos[1,k]
    j <- combos[2,k]
    print(paste("intersecting",i,j))
    assign(paste("int",i,j,sep="_"),gIntersection(get(i), get(j), byid = FALSE))
}
```

You may not need this step below since you have all the new `int_pi_pj` SpatialPolygons as separate objects, but if you want them in a list:

```
int <- mget(ls(pattern='^int_.'))
rm(list = ls(pattern='^int_.')   #cleanup
```

Then you can access the items in your list with `$`:

```
plot(int$int_p1_p2)
```

EDIT: In the above, when there is no overlap, the variable will be NULL.If you don't want to even see the combinations where there is no overlap, you could add this `if` statement to the same `for` loop:

```
for(k in seq_along(combos[1,])){
    i <- combos[1,k]
    j <- combos[2,k]
    print(paste("intersecting",i,j))
    if(gIntersects(get(i), get(j), byid = FALSE)){
        assign(paste("int",i,j,sep="_"),gIntersection(get(i), get(j), byid = FALSE))
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot! it works great and I have learn a lot about R data processing and its almost immense possibilities ! Great idea to use combn() and another tools ! only one remark:  rm(ls(pattern='^int_.')   #cleanup doesn't work for my, but rm(list = ls(pattern='^int_.'))  does.

Comment: My pleasure! Thinking about this also helped me with my own work so everyone wins! I edited the answer to include the `list =` in the `rm()` function. I'm not sure why some systems need the argument list specific, but it does work on mine so including it makes it a more general answer