# Loop to intersect points with polygons in R for each individual

Tags: shapefile, r, intersection, loop, for-loop

I have a shapefile with points for 6 individuals and another shapefile with 6 polygons (one per individual). Every individual has the same id in both files.

**I want to intersect both layers in order to obtain, for each individual, the points within the corresponding polygon.**
I've tried with only one individual, using the function `raster::intersect()` and it works perfectly. However, I will have to repeat this process for other animals so I would like to have a loop that could do this automatically (but I am not very familiar with loops).

I've tried several options, and so far this was the only one that worked partially:

```
for (i in unique(SLO_repr$id)) {
         for (j in unique(HR95_all$id)) {
                 if ((!is.na(SLO_repr$id[i])) == (!is.na(HR95_all$id[j]))) {
                         a <- raster::intersect(SLO_repr, HR95_all)
                         writeOGR(a, dsn= getwd(), paste0("points_withinHR", "_", i), driver = "ESRI Shapefile",overwrite_layer=TRUE)}
         }
 }
```

The problem with this one is that, in each shapefile, all points within each polygon are included. So, the `raster::intersect()` function worked, but it seems I didn't select the `i` and `j` properly...?

To build this loop, I followed this question: [Loop to check multiple polygons overlap in r](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156660/loop-to-check-multiple-polygons-overlap-in-r)

I was also wondering if I really need to have a nested loop? Because all id's are the same, so in the condition, when it gets on `i` for `SLO_repr$id`, it should select the same value for `HR95_all$id`?

So I've tried this loop:

```
 for (i in unique(SLO_repr$id)) {
                 if ((!is.na(SLO_repr$id[i])) == (!is.na(HR95_all$id[i]))) {
                         a <- raster::intersect(SLO_repr[[i]], HR95_all)
                         writeOGR(a, dsn= getwd(), paste0("points_withinHR", "_", i), driver = "ESRI Shapefile",overwrite_layer=TRUE)}
         }
```

But I get this error: "`Error in as.vector(y) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`"

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use one loop, where you subset the point layer by unique `id`. Then intersect these subsetted points by polygon with same `id`. Code below suggesting that there is one polygon for each unique point `id`, otherwise subset it in same way as points.

```
for (id in unique(points$id)){
    id_points <- points[points$id==id,]
    sp_points <- intersect(id_points,polygons[id,])
    writeOGR(sp_points,dsn=getwd(), layer=paste0("points_withinHR_", id), driver = "ESRI Shapefile",overwrite_layer=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!!!